# Gradle task vs plugin vs task type?

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

```
apply plugin: 'war'

war {
    ...
}
```

From what I understand:
There is a [gradle war plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/war_plugin.html) which I get available from the `apply plugin: 'war'` line, that allows me to use the war task declared via the `war { ... }` which is of type [war](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.War.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you apply the Gradle War plugin, a task with the name `war` is created automatically. When you refer to `war { ... }` in your build script, you are effectively configuring the `war` task instance with the help of a closure.

```
war {
    baseName = 'example'
}
```

does the same thing as

```
war.baseName = 'example'
```

The benefit of the closure syntax is that you can configure the task instance through multiple statements. It also becomes more readable and looks more like a DSL.

The actual type of the task named `war` is [War](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.War.html). You can always find out the type of task from the command line via `gradle help --task <task-name>`.

You can also get some information about the type of variable in your build script:

```
task printType {
    doLast {
        println war
    }
}
```

Executing the task will print out the following:

```
$ gradle printType
:printType
task ':war'
```

Answer (score 1):

The "war" block below the "apply" isn't defining a task, it's simply a configuration block used by the plugin.

Comment: To be precised `war` in this particular example is defined via an _extension_.

Comment: So at what point does the war task type come into play? Does the plugin use that task type to create the war task that I then extend from using the config block?

Comment: I suggest you download the Gradle distro and read the "User Guide" PDF from top to bottom.  You need to understand the roles that tasks play and their relationship with other entities.